# JSON files to array

Tags: sql, json, database, web

I have a heart.json file that I need transfer to a database and looking for a solution. In the file I have the following data:

```
      {"activities-heart":[{"dateTime":"2016-04-08","value":{"customHeartRateZones":[],"heartRateZones":[{"caloriesOut":1720.78208,"max":99,"min":30,"minutes":972,"name":"Out of Range"},{"caloriesOut":313.1456,"max":139,"min":99,"minutes":59,"name":"Fat Burn"},{"caloriesOut":0,"max":169,"min":139,"minutes":0,"name":"Cardio"},{"caloriesOut":0,"max":220,"min":169,"minutes":0,"name":"Peak"}],"restingHeartRate":73}}]
    ,"activities-heart-intraday":{"dataset":[
{"time":"00:00:00","value":83},
{"time":"00:01:00","value":80},
{"time":"00:02:00","value":76},
{"time":"00:03:00","value":78},
{"time":"00:04:00","value":78},
{"time":"00:05:00","value":79},
{"time":"00:06:00","value":79},
{"time":"00:07:00","value":78},
{"time":"00:08:00","value":76},
{"time":"00:09:00","value":77},
{"time":"00:10:00","value":83},
{"time":"00:11:00","value":81},
{"time":"00:12:00","value":80},
{"time":"00:13:00","value":80},
{"time":"00:14:00","value":80},
{"time":"00:15:00","value":75},
{"time":"00:16:00","value":75},
{"time":"00:17:00","value":76},
{"time":"00:18:00","value":76},
{"time":"00:19:00","value":76},
{"time":"00:20:00","value":78},
{"time":"00:21:00","value":83},
{"time":"00:22:00","value":76},
{"time":"00:23:00","value":74},
{"time":"00:24:00","value":75},
{"time":"00:25:00","value":74},
{"time":"00:26:00","value":75},
{"time":"00:27:00","value":75},
{"time":"00:28:00","value":75},
{"time":"00:29:00","value":77},
{"time":"00:30:00","value":82},
{"time":"00:31:00","value":82}
```

I am looking at putting the "time" value and "value" value into the database from this file but have no idea as to how please would someone be kind enough to take the time to help me out.

Comment: What language are you working with on the web?  PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your JSON converted to a database script that inserts the values in the database. Now go and try to find how to create the database and table by yourself.
You should install a database server in your machine, then create a database, then create a table, then run the script below.
The table should have 2 columns (named time and value) and their types should be "time" and integer (or numeric depending on your database).
I'm assuming this is a relational database you're talking.
If along the way you have any doubts on how you do any of the parts, be free to ask more.

```
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:00:00",83);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:01:00",80);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:02:00",76);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:03:00",78);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:04:00",78);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:05:00",79);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:06:00",79);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:07:00",78);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:08:00",76);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:09:00",77);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:10:00",83);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:11:00",81);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:12:00",80);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:13:00",80);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:14:00",80);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:15:00",75);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:16:00",75);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:17:00",76);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:18:00",76);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:19:00",76);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:20:00",78);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:21:00",83);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:22:00",76);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:23:00",74);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:24:00",75);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:25:00",74);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:26:00",75);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:27:00",75);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:28:00",75);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:29:00",77);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:30:00",82);
insert into your_table (time, value) values ("00:31:00",82);
```